# Rails 2 + Microsoft SQL Server: ActiveRecord returns -1 but SQL server returns records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why does `ActiveRecord` always return `-1` whether it's through a browser or through the console?

SQL statement:

```
SELECT category.categoryname,  sum(lineitems.qty) as totalSales,  
sum(lineitems.qty*size.sizeship) as volume,  
sum(lineitems.qty*lineitems.purcprice) AS totmerchandise  FROM category, products, 
orders, shipments, lineitems, size  WHERE 
category.categoryid = products.categoryid  AND products.productid = 
lineitems.productid  AND lineitems.posshipid = shipments.posshipid  AND 
shipments.posorderid = orders.posorderid  AND size.sizeid = products.size  AND 
category.categoryid NOT IN (77,79)  AND orders.orderstatus in 
(1,4,5)  AND orders.ordercomplete = 1  AND numbotincase > 0  AND orders.date >= 
'20130501'  AND orders.date < '20130531'  GROUP BY 
category.categoryname  ORDER BY category.categoryname`
```

When I execute this in Microsoft SQL server, it loads a bunch of records. 
However, in Rails when I try to do this:

```
query_for_category_bottles_volume_totalsales = "SELECT category.categoryname,  
sum(lineitems.qty) as totalSales,  sum(lineitems.qty*size.sizeship) as volume,  
sum(lineitems.qty*lineitems.purcprice) AS totmerchandise  FROM category, products, 
orders, shipments, lineitems, size  WHERE category.categoryid = products.categoryid  
AND products.productid = lineitems.productid  AND lineitems.posshipid = 
shipments.posshipid  AND shipments.posorderid = orders.posorderid  AND 
size.sizeid = products.size  AND category.categoryid NOT IN (77,79)  AND 
orders.orderstatus in (1,4,5)  AND orders.ordercomplete = 1  AND numbotincase > 0  
AND orders.date >= '20130501'  AND orders.date < '20130531'  GROUP BY 
category.categoryname  ORDER BY category.categoryname"

category_bottles_volume_totalsales = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query_for_category_bottles_volume_totalsales)
```

This happens not only for this query, but something simple like this as well: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from orders where id = 987;")`. However, in the console when I do `Order.find(987)` it returns a record.

Comment: is category_bottles_volume_totalsales set to -1?

Comment: nope, that variable is created on that line

Comment: Please add your question at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to change the way ActiveRecord was making the query.

```
  database = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

  query_for_category_bottle_casecost_case_price = "SELECT ..."

  category_bottle_casecost_case_price = database.select_all(query_for_category_bottle_casecost_case_price)
```